# c++ runtime error when using vectors push back and iterator

Tags: c++, vector, runtime

Hi I'm trying to solve a algorithm problem and when I submit my code on an online judge I keep on getting a runtime error. I have no idea why it is happening.
Here is the problem that I'm trying to solve.
[image: problem][image: problem]

The code is as follows. It works fine for the sample input and outputs in visual studio. I haven't yet met inputs and outputs that does not work well or actually meet the runtime error. Only the online judge is giving the runtime error so I can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int m;
    int c1;
    int c2;
    cin >> n >> m >> c1 >> c2;
    vector<int> p = {};
    vector<int> q = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        p.push_back(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        q.push_back(temp);
    }
    vector<int> distance = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < q.size(); ++j)
        {
            distance.push_back(abs(p[i] - q[j]) + abs(c1 - c2));
        }
    }
    sort(distance.begin(), distance.end());
    int min = distance[0];
    int count = 0;;
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(distance.size()); ++i)
    {
        if (distance[0] == distance[i])
            count++;
        else
            break;
    }
    cout << min << " " << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider that size of `distance` vector can be 0?

Comment: It would help if you gave an explanation (with an example) of what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Can't reproduce the runtime error.

Comment: m and n are both equal to or larger than 1 so the size of distance could not be 0

Comment: @SeJinKim Is there a restriction on m and n max value?

Comment: @Amadeusz yes I have edited the question so you could click problem and see the exact problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: @BoBTFish I've edited the question and you could check the problem now.

Comment: If the code "works fine for the sample input and outputs in visual studio" what inputs and outputs doesn't it work for?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I haven't really met the inputs and outputs that does not work for, so to me it's all fine, but this online judge system is the problem which is giving the runtime error.

Comment: "`for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(distance.size()); ++i)`" don't cast `std::vector::size()` to `int`, use the proper type for `i` and `count`.

Comment: Which online judge, what exactly is the error message?

Comment: @Swordfish what do you mean by the proper type for i? The reason I did the casting is because it gave me a warning since int is signed whereas size() is unsigned

Comment: @SeJinKim `i`, `j`, `m`, `n` and `count` should be of type `std::size_t`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm preparing to participate in ACM-ICPC which is a programming competition and they've opened a practice session to solve some problems which are judged on online. Unfortunately only the contestants are able to submit it so you won't be able to check it out. And the only error message I get is the judge result that says "run error" and that's it

Comment: if n and m are 500,000 then distance uses 1TB of memory, presumably the online judge doesn't allow allocation of this amount of memory. if you think about the problem a little more you don't need to record all the values of distance

Comment: @Swordfish thanks but still getting the error

Comment: @SeJinKim The thing is, an `int` would have overflown for big `m` and `n`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks now I don't get the run error!!

Comment: I think @AlanBirtles has the right clue here - I think the question deliberately has quite large inputs to force you to come up with a clever way of solving the problem that does not involve storing everything at once.

Comment: @BoBTFish If there were no mem limitation it wouldn't have worked with `int`s. And it's simply good practice to use the appropriate types.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` and `m` are both the maximum allowed value of `500,000` then distance will have `500,000 * 500,000` elements which will use 1TB of memory. Due to vector growing as you `push_back` you could actually need around 2TB of memory in total. The online judge presumably doesn't allow you to use this much memory.

If you rethink your algorithm to not store the values of distance it will probably work.

You should lways use `reserve` on `std::vector` if you know the size in advance as it should cause the vector to allocate exactly the right amount of memory and avoid copying to new blocks of memory as the vector grows.